# VTK format display problem in Paraview+GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, 3d, raster-conversion, grass-7.0, geology

I would like to create geological 3D model from lithological layers of an area.I have converted the raster file to VTK(**r3.to.vtk** command) in GRASS and intended to display it in Paraview. Although I open the vtk file and click apply button, the program(Paraview) always freezes. Why does it happen?

Comment: Probably a size issue? How many MB has your exported file? How long did you wait to resolve the issue? Are there other bottle necks such as downloading the file via network, conventional HDD?

Comment: I exported 3 vtk files. The size of each is average 4.90GB (pretty much huh?). It took 15-20 minutes to resolve but there is no problem about HDD. I have pretty large area to save them. I don't think there is a network problem. Furthermore I don't see records of vtk files when I import them in Paraview.

Comment: I dont think that your HDD is too small, but rather too slow. How much RAM do you available. I have to say 4.9 GiB is pretty much. Do you see any chance to split up those files into tiles or something before hand? Actually I don't even know if Paraview can handle such big files.

Answer (score 1):

After I had arranged CRS(Coordinate Reference System) from **"g.region"** according to the raster file that I worked on, I got the satisfactory result. At first I selected the CRS of vector file which was also the similar of the raster file but that didn't work. So it's a good tip to make sure the CRS is correct or smoothly referenced from the correct file. Some problems may occur because of CRS related issues.